# jQuery - better way of coding several repeating lines

Tags: jquery

Is there a better way of writing the code below, keep in mind there is no set minimum or maximum number and the format will remain the same: checkba0## and link-ba0## etc.

```
    if(data.config.checkba01 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba01").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba02 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba02").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba03 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba03").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba04 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba04").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba05 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba05").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba06 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba06").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba07 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba07").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba08 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba08").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba09 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba09").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba010 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba010").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba011 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba011").toggleClass("hide"); }
    if(data.config.checkba012 == false) { $(element).find(".link-ba012").toggleClass("hide"); }
```

Thanks

Comment: If you know how a `for` loop works in JavaScript, it should be reasonably clear how to replace the digits in each expression with a loop variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is redundant logic. To fix this, you can use a loop to iterate over the items. This will reduce the redundant statements in the given implementation.

#### Check following code:

```
let i = 1;
let upperLimit = 12; // change it according to your requirements
while (i <= upperLimit) {
    const propertyName = `checkba0${i}`;
    const selector = `.link-ba0${i}`;

    if (data.config[propertyName] === false) {
        $(element).find(selector).toggleClass("hide");
    }

    i++;
}
```

Above code will seperate the dynamic contents from the static code.